# account.number is required (recurly)

Tags: python, recurly

I'm trying to create a Recurly account using their python API, and keep hitting the same error:

```
def upsert_recurly_account(office):
    try:
        account = recurly.Account.get(office.pk)
    except recurly.errors.NotFoundError:
        logger.warning("Creating new recurly account for pk %s" % office.pk)
        account = recurly.Account(account_code=office.pk)
    else:
        logger.info("Recurly account %s already exists, we will update it")

account.email = office.manager.email
account.first_name = office.manager.first_name
account.last_name = office.manager.last_name
account.company_name = '%s - %s' % (office.legal_name, office.name)
account.vat_number = office.tax_id
account.tax_exempt = office.tax_exempt

billing_info = recurly.BillingInfo()

billing_info.first_name = office.manager.first_name
billing_info.last_name = office.manager.last_name
billing_info.address1 = office.address1
billing_info.address2 = office.address2
billing_info.city = office.city
billing_info.country = office.country
billing_info.zip = office.postal_code
billing_info.phone = office.phone
billing_info.vat_number = office.tax_id

account.billing_info = billing_info

account.save()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ValidationError:required: account.number is required
```

Manually adding

```
account.number = 1234
```

Doesn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating a new Account with nested billing info you need to provide a valid credit card number in the `billing_info` hash like so:

```
billing_info.number = 123
```

There are other mandatory fields (like `month` and `year`) when creating a new account with nested billing info. Please read [the docs](https://docs.recurly.com/api/billing-info#update-billing-info-credit-card)

Comment: What is the point of tokens if you have to pass card numbers to backend?

Answer (score 0):

Account.number isn't a valid Recurly field - it looks like you need to be passing through account_code - see the sample at https://docs.recurly.com/api/accounts#create-account